# How to Schedule Run all apex tests on daily basis

Tags: apex, code-coverage, scheduled-apex, apextestrunresult

How to Schedule Run all apex tests on a daily basis?
Currently, we are performing it manually is there any way we can automate it?

Comment: You can write apex scheduler class that will use tooling api service: runTestsAsynchronous. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to automate it. You can subscribe to an app like GearSet to schedule automations, you can set up a CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) system to run tests on a schedule, you can use the basic core features of Windows or Linux systems to run a Windows Task or Cronjob, deploy a container to Heroku or AWS, etc, or you could write Apex code in a scheduled class to run at the desired time. Each solution will have different technical requirements, may require a subscription, etc.